# Manual entries not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I know this will be a bit stupid, but I'm struggling with setting up manual entries in grub.

This is the entry (Darkmatter) I write, which doesn't show up in grub bootloader:

[image: My entry]

But, if I copy-paste a ready entry like this:

[image: Ready entry]

It magically shows up. I'm trying to see the differences, but can't see any. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Note: I didn't cut out the Ubuntu entry in screenshot to help be understood where my entry is.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Isn't your entry in the advanced options submenu? Looks like it should appear there. Are you directly editing grub.cfg? You should add your entry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, make sure the file is executable and run `sudo update-grub` then. Your entry should appear then in Grub's main menu.

Comment: Damn, how stupid I am. I was indeed editing grub.cfg directly, but the reason why it wasn't appearing is that I was adding an extra $ to the end of $SOURCE_NAME, realized this when I added it to 40_custom file and encountered the $ syntax error. Didn't know anything about 40_custom file, thank you very much.

terdon, I'm sorry for the trouble. I will remember to do this next time.